# show product atribute value only in admin order details magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, attributes, admin

Hi i need to show the **product** **attribute** **value** in **admin** **order** **details** **section**, i don't want to show this attribute on frontend to users , is there any way to do this

thanks

Comment: You might look for something like this: $user = $auth->getIdentity(); if ($user->isAdmin())... but for any kind of answer you should update your question and fill in the essentials of your code.

Comment: i want to add the value of that attribute hiddenly with the order which shouldn't see on frontend but visible on admin order section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
This is the code with which I am able to show the custom attribute value in the Magento admin order view:

```
<?php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('x'));
echo $product->getX();
```

Place this code in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/templates/sales/items/column/name.phtml` where `x` is the code for your attribute - replace it with your attribute code.
In admin, attribute properties should be:

```
Values Required = no
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end = no
Scope = global
```